# ERROR with Stripe Checkout: One-Time + Subscription Payment Buttons on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, json, stripe-payments

**UPDATED** I built a pricing page that uses [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout) to use both a One-Time payment button for product 1 and a Subscription payment button for product 2.

[image]

**My goal** is to redirect the one time payment button to Stripe Checkout with a one time payment, and separately redirect the subscription payment to a checkout with a recurring payment.

According to STRIPE this can be done using Subscription as the Mode in the CheckoutSession in create-checkout-session.php (sample project) :

> The mode of the Checkout Session. Required when using prices or setup
> mode. Pass subscription if the Checkout Session includes at least one
> recurring item.

Contrary to the Stripe Docs the following line of code: `'mode' => 'subscription',` activates subscription payments ONLY, but it doesnt redirect one time payments. For one-time payments to work I must change it to: `'mode' => 'payment',` but then subscription payments don't work.

Here's the php code in question:

```
 <?php
    
    require_once 'shared.php';
    
    $domain_url = $config['domain'];
    
    // Create new Checkout Session for the order
    // Other optional params include:
    // [billing_address_collection] - to display billing address details on the page
    // [customer] - if you have an existing Stripe Customer ID
    // [payment_intent_data] - lets capture the payment later
    // [customer_email] - lets you prefill the email input in the form
    // For full details see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
    
    // ?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} means the redirect will have the session ID set as a query param
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'success_url' => $domain_url . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        'cancel_url' => $domain_url . '/canceled.html',
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'mode' => 'subscription',
        'line_items' => [[
          'price' => $body->priceId,
          'quantity' => 1,
      ]]
    ]);
    
    echo json_encode(['sessionId' => $checkout_session['id']]);
```

And here's the javascript code:

```
// Create a Checkout Session with the selected plan ID
var createCheckoutSession = function(priceId) {
  return fetch("./create-checkout-session.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      priceId: priceId
    })
  }).then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  });
};

// Handle any errors returned from Checkout
var handleResult = function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById("error-message");
    displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
  }
};

/* Get your Stripe publishable key to initialize Stripe.js */
fetch("./config.php")
  .then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    var publishableKey = json.publishableKey;
    var subscriptionPriceId = json.subscriptionPrice;
    var onetimePriceId = json.onetimePrice;

    var stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);
    // Setup event handler to create a Checkout Session when button is clicked
    document
      .getElementById("subscription-btn")
      .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        createCheckoutSession(subscriptionPriceId).then(function(data) {
          // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
          stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: data.sessionId
            })
            .then(handleResult);
        });
      });

    // Setup event handler to create a Checkout Session when button is clicked
    document
      .getElementById("onetime-btn")
      .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        createCheckoutSession(onetimePriceId).then(function(data) {
          // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
          stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: data.sessionId
            })
            .then(handleResult);
        });
      });
      
  });
```

**Is it even possible to have both one time payments and recurring payments on the same page with Stripe Checkout? How can I accomplish this?**

**Update** according to Bemn:

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'success_url' => $domain_url . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  'cancel_url' => $domain_url . '/canceled.html',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'mode' => $body->mode
    'line_items' => [[
    'price' => $body->price_xxx,
    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],

  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => $body->price_zzz,
    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]]
]);

echo json_encode(['sessionId' => $checkout_session['id']]);
```

And the JS:

```
// Create a Checkout Session with the selected plan ID
var createCheckoutSession = function(priceId, mode) {
  return fetch("./create-checkout-session.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      priceId: priceId,
      mode: mode // <-- passing the mode, e.g. 'payment' or 'subscription'
    })
  }).then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  });
};
```

And the HTML:

```
<div data-stripe-priceid="pricexxx" data-stripe-mode="payment" id="onetime-btn" class="bold mt-2 d-inline-block w-100-after-md max-width-xxs py-2 btn btn-secondary">Ore Time</div>
    
<div data-stripe-priceid="pricexxx" data-stripe-mode="subscription" id="subscription-btn" class="bold mt-2 d-inline-block w-100-after-md max-width-xxs py-2 btn btn-secondary">Ore Time</div>
```

Comment: Yes, not sure of the documentation but I've seen it many times multiple platforms both options present. :)

Comment: How do you implement that solution?  I've tried to solve it on the checkout-sessions.php file. Do you know a better way?

Comment: I remember creating a 'product' from within the Stripe dashboard then in the code creating 'plans' (i.e. payment plans) on the fly depending on the subscription amount. In the backend I used the Stripe API like this:`$new_plan = \Stripe\Plan::create([
 'id' => $amount,
 'product' => $product_id,
 'nickname' => $amount / 100 . ' GBP per month',
 'interval' => 'month',
 'currency' => 'gbp',
 'amount' => $amount,
]);` where `$product_id` is taken from the Stripe dashboard. This was about 18 months ago though so not sure how current it is.

Comment: Then I created a new subscription like,
`$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
 'customer' => $customer->id,
 'items' => [['plan' => $amount]],
]);` (nb. I named the plans according to the amount so I could easily check if a plan for a particular amount already existed). Not sure how helpful this is for you, it looks like you're using Stripe in a different way to how I did. I do suspect however that you need to look at 'products' and 'plans'.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans

Answer (score 5):

#### Is it even possible to have both one time payments and recurring payments on the same page with Stripe Checkout?

**Yes.** The key is you should pass **the correct options** to generate the corresponding Stripe Checkout session ID.

#### How can I accomplish this?

- Backend: Have a function to accept **Stripe's price ID** and **payment mode** as input and return a Stripe Checkout session ID as the output.
- Frontend: Pass **payment mode** information to `/create-checkout-session.php`. (see the Note if you are unable to do so)

---

### Details

The following solution assuming that:

1. You generate a Stripe Checkout Session ID at the backend. That ID will then pass to `.createCheckoutSession()` in js frontend.
2. You have a 1-time product (let's call it *PAY*) and a recurrent subscription (let's call it *SUB*).

#### Frontend

I think you are close. What you need to do is passing the `mode` information to your API endpoint as well:

```js
// Create a Checkout Session with the selected plan ID
var createCheckoutSession = function(priceId, mode) { // <-- add a mode parameter
  return fetch("./create-checkout-session.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      priceId: priceId,
      mode: mode // <-- passing the mode, e.g. 'payment' or 'subscription'
    })
  }).then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  });
};
```

If so, each checkout button in the page should have corresponding info of the priceId and payment mode. You can do so by storing them using data attribute:

```html
<div data-stripe-priceid="price_yyy" data-stripe-mode="subscription">Recurrent</div>
<div data-stripe-priceid="price_zzz" data-stripe-mode="payment">1-time</div>
```

If so, you can get the data attributes by e.g. a `click` event.

**Note:** If you cannot add an extra param to indicate mode, you neeed to identify if the given price ID is a 1-time or recurrent product in the backend. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object?lang=php#price_object-type for more details.

#### Backend

Here are 2 sample code snippets from Stripe's documentation. **Direct copying of them does not work**.

Reference for *PAY*: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'unit_amount' => 2000,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);
```

In your case, you may not need to define `'price_data'`. Instead, you should use `'price'`, like the next example.

Reference for *SUB*: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#create-session

```php
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/canceled.html',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'mode' => 'subscription',
  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => $body->priceId,
    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
]);
```

2. Take a look at this reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create. For `line_items`, you can just simply using `'price'` and pass the price ID (e.g. `price_xxx`), which means your `'line_items'` will looks like this:

```php
'line_items' => [[
  'price' => $body->priceId,
  'quantity' => 1,
]],
```

For `'mode'`, use the value from your API request. It should be something like:

```php
'mode' => $body->mode
```

Which means in your backend you better define a function (e.g. `generate_checkout_session`) to:

- parse the json body received in the API request
- get `priceId` and `mode` from the parsed data
- use the `priceId` and `mode` in `\Stripe\Checkout\Session::create` and
- returns the `checkout_session` ID

Hope this (and the reference urls) can help you.

Comment: I am likely missing something somewhere but I wonder how this works if a customer is buying a mixture of items requiring one-off payments and items paid for with a subscription in a single transaction-?

Comment: @wkille I am afraid you cannot do that (at least you cannot generate a Stripe Checkout session mixing two kinds of items).

Comment: I think I was following correctly until you got to this part: "Which means in your backend you better define a function accepting priceId and mode from your API request, and returns a checkout_session ID."

Comment: I added what I got from your solution, it still doesnt work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChosenJuan your backend `create-checkout-session.php` file will receive a JSON string from the frontend. `$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([ ...` doesn't know what `priceId` and `mode` are automatically so you have to parse the JSON string, assign the values of `priceId` and `mode` received from the frontend to php variables and pass those variables to the create Stripe session function in @Bemn's answer in place of `priceId` and `mode`. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/

Comment: @ChosenJuan having a function is just a **suggestion** for you to manage your code better. The critical part is that the values of `'price'` and '`mode`' should use the data you received (i.e. `$body->priceId` and `$body->mode`). @wkille did mention the fact that you need to parse the json body submitted in order to retrieve the `priceId` and `mode`. I am not a expert of php so you may need to find out how to do it.

Comment: @ChosenJuan please accept the answer if it helped you to solve tour issue.

Answer (score 2):

For subscription we actually need to set interval, which is not need to set in one time purses. Probably this error happening for this reason.
Add recurring can be solve recurring error.

```
recurring: {
   interval: 'month' // 'month' | 'year'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your Session you can pass both a Price for the recurring amount charged on the subscription and another Price for the one-time fee you want to charge. You can combine multiple recurring Prices and one-time Prices overall.

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => $domain_url . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => $domain_url . '/canceled.html',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
    'line_items' => [
      // Add a one-time Price for $10
      [
        'price' => 'price_123', 
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
      // Add another one-time Price for $23
      [
        'price' => 'price_345', 
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
      // Add a recurring Price for $100 monthly
      [
        'price' => 'price_ABC', 
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
]);
```

The code above will create a session with 3 line items. One for $100 monthly, one for $10 just once and one for $23 just once. The total for the session would be $133 on the first payment. It will also start a subscription for $100 a month and future invoices will be for $100 as expected.

Comment: This justs adds up all of the prices together. I wanted to have one button to trigger one time payments and another button to trigger monthly payments.

Comment: @ChosenJuan Ah sorry I misunderstood the question. The idea here would be to have two buttons in your form that call your server which creates a Checkout Session with the right line items based on what the customer is buying exactly.

Comment: Yes exactly, I will have two buttons that redirect to either a subscription plan or a one time fee. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @ChosenJuan I'm not sure what part is blocking you exactly though. Your server-side code needs to pass the right parameters to the Session creation based on whether you want a one-time payment or a subscription. This means passing the right `line_items` and the right `mode`. Your JS code client-side would send the right information to the server for that reason. After creating the Session you can redirect client-side.

Comment: The line_items are not the problem, the problem is the mode can only redirect to subscription payments or one time payments, but not both. How can I change the mode to accept both?  Or do you know a Json or JS fix to this issue?

Comment: It's impossible to "accept both" that's your issue right now. You just need to tweak your code to change `mode` based on whether the line items are recurring or not that's all. You simply need to tweak your code to check the included Prices and whether they are recurring, and if not pass `mode: "payment"`

Comment: How do I acomplish that? JavaScript? Can you show me

Answer (score 0):

What I have got is that you just need to add a check for either it is one-time or subscription here is what you can do:

```
JS FILE CHANGES:

var createCheckoutSession = function(priceId, $mode) {
  return fetch("./create-checkout-session.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      priceId: priceId,
      paymentType: $mode, // This vary based on the button clicked either one-time or subscription.
    })
  }).then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  });
};

/* Get your Stripe publishable key to initialize Stripe.js */
fetch("./config.php")
  .then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    var publishableKey = json.publishableKey;
    var subscriptionPriceId = json.subscriptionPrice;
    var onetimePriceId = json.onetimePrice;

    var stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);
    // Setup event handler to create a Checkout Session when button is clicked
    document
      .getElementById("subscription-btn")
      .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        createCheckoutSession(subscriptionPriceId, 'subscription').then(function(data) {
          // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
          stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: data.sessionId
            })
            .then(handleResult);
        });
      });

    // Setup event handler to create a Checkout Session when button is clicked
    document
      .getElementById("onetime-btn")
      .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        createCheckoutSession(onetimePriceId, 'onetime').then(function(data) {
          // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
          stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: data.sessionId
            })
            .then(handleResult);
        });
      });
      
  });
```

Now we need to make changes in PHP file:

```
PHP FILE CHANGES:

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'success_url' => $domain_url . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        'cancel_url' => $domain_url . '/canceled.html',
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'mode' => $body->paymentType, // Here is what we have got from front-end
        'line_items' => [[
          'price' => $body->priceId,
          'quantity' => 1,
      ]]
    ]);
```